# Why do i always get changed Thread Id when hosting on another thread with wcf?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

In my application I **host** a WCF service:

```
private void StartService()
{
    m_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(...));
    m_serviceHost.Open();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    Thread t = new Thread(StartService);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    // ...
}
```

The service itself has just one method:

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message '{0}' received on thread {1} : MessageLoop = 
        {2}", message, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode(), Application.MessageLoop), 
        "MessagingService.SendMessage()");
}
```

When the client calls this operation I get the following responses:

```
Message 'hello client : message 9 recieved on thread **12**
Message 'hello client : message 9 recieved on thread **15**
Message 'hello client : message 9 recieved on thread **17**
...
```

Why does the thread id always change? When I created the ServiceHost I only put him on another thread! **im not re-putting him on another thread each time... only once**

How can i put the host in another thread  (like i did) and to get only single background thread id ?

Comment: What InstanceContext (PerCall, Single, PerSession) and Concurrency mode (single, multiple or reentrant) settings have you applied to your service?

Comment: nothing. empty deceleration... but when i added  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)] - it still shows me different thread id

Comment: That's the default ConcurrencyMode anyway.

Comment: so why do i see each request a different ID ? How can i accomplish this ?

Comment: Why would you want to cripple the server to run single threaded?

Comment: Why are you using the hashcode of the thread? Use the ManagedThreadId property instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx)

Comment: i think you right.. let me check :)

Comment: @geers : still - changed ID... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC correctly the ConcurrencyMode.Single does not guarantee that a single thread is used...it guarantees that only a single thread can access the service instance...thus preventing concurrency issues that might arrise if two (or more) threads use the same service instance (state might get corrupted for instance).

I guess you want to enforce one thread to handle all the calls so everything gets done sequentially and no state gets corrupted. But with the default InstanceContextMode (PerCall) each call gets its own service instance anyway. And with the ConcurrencyMode set to single you are sure that only one thread accesses a service instance.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, 
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public string ReturnMessage()
    {
        return String.Format("Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: my test was with single ( as singleton) - and there i saw the difference

Comment: Well that just means there is only one service instance that handles all the calls. With a instance context mode and concurrency mode of single...every call will have to wait in line. That's really crippling the performance of your service.

Answer (score 2):

You *started* the service on another thread, but the ServiceHost itself uses multiple threads to process requests.

If your service is not thread safe, you can force it to be executed in a single threaded manner by decorating the service class with a [`ServiceBehaviorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554644.aspx) and setting [`ConcurrencyMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) to `Single`:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class ServiceClass
{
}
```

Comment: IIRC correctly the ConcurrencyMode.Single does not guarantee that a single thread is used...it guarantees that only a single thread can access the service instance...thus preventing concurrency issues that might arrise if two (or more) threads use the same service instance (state might get corrupted for instance).

Comment: @geers you right. ive tested it  with multi CLIENTS opend and if i use the single mode : so until the message box releases - the other commands waits in line. please make your comment as a answer so i can choose it.

Comment: It's basically what Richard said rephrased. The concurrency mode ensures thread safety if your service is not thread safe by not allowing multiple thread to access a service instance simultanously.